# How to get Cell ID and Location Area code in android 9 ( Pie ) devices without using GPS?

Tags: android, android-9.0-pie, cellinfo

I tried getAllCellInfo(), getCellLocation() and getNeighboringCellInfo() to get Cell ID and Location Area Code.
I got the values(Cell ID and Location Area Code) when the GPS is turned into ON state and Without GPS these methods return null

So what i do to get the Cell ID and Location Area Code without using GPS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Telephony information now relies on device location setting

If the user has disabled device location on a device running Android 9, the following methods don't provide results:

```
getAllCellInfo()
listen()
getCellLocation()
getNeighboringCellInfo()
```

Comment: Hello Jeosh! Have you found any solution to get cellinfo without GPS enabled?